# ms access conditional formatting statement for recently updated data

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Is there a way in MS access 2007 to create a conditional formatting rule that will highlight any field that has been updated in the past 7 days?

Currently I have a rule that highlights any information that is added in the previous week by field value is between Now()-7 and Now(). I'd like to open up the option to modifying old entries that week and have those highlighting as well.

Thanks.

EDIT:
Essentially the database dates back from approximately 6 months. It tracks progress on projects and employees enter task details in a subform of the project.

```
Date       Employee    Task 
3/14/2012   David      Talked to Remou *about ms-access* 
8/1/2012    John       Solved world hunger
```

** denotes updated information, and although the task happened on 3/14, I would like to display the changes with conditional formatting. Currently the only thing that would highlight is the 8/1 event.

Comment: I am afraid your question is not clear to me. It seems that you are already highlighting rows that are changed in the last 7 days. Perhaps you could post some sample data and indicate which rows you want highlighted?

Comment: I will edit the original post.

Comment: So you wish to compare the current task text with previous task text and highlight the differences, is that correct?

Comment: Does your table include an updated date?

Comment: No updated date currently, but that is actually a really good (and fairly obvious) work around I can't believe I didn't think of. But yes, to refer to the original question I was hoping to fully automate the process by utilizing a query to note the date one of the 15 employees went in and changed an entry. Also, the whole entry can be hi-lighted, it doesn't have to just be the edited part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the easiest way is to add an update date and a username. It won't give you a highlighted text difference, but it will be much easier to implement. As an aside, I always add a created timestamp, created user, updated timestamp and updated user to any user maintained tables. It saves so much trouble, because Access does not automatically add this information.

Comment: Added an update column and conditional formatting colors any fields that have been updated in the past week. Not my ideal solution but as close as access will let me get to it, thanks for the help Remou.

Comment: It is possible to have a rich text memo field, another field with the previous text and compare, but I am not sure that it is worth the trouble for the benefit.